# case null SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

How to check for null in case statement in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometime you need `case isnull(column, 99) when 99 then "null" when 1 then ....`

Comment: Do you know why this is true? My SQL database will not accept "case when data is null" at all.

Answer (score -1):

Using Case in Select Query:

Example:

```
SELECT UserID, UserName, CASE(UserAmendId) AS UID WHEN 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END 
FROM UserTable
```

It shows records with field UID=true where its Value=0, otherwise it show False where its Value is Null.

> Table Name: UserTable
>   Columns:  UserID (int), UserName (varchar(50)), UserAmendID (int)